# Could have been disappointed - is that a correct usage of could have been?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

It is to my understanding that 'could have been' talks about a possible present situation that have not happened but is possible in the present and should be followed by a verb in a continuous form.
In the context of - "I'm glad I have bought the product before the sale because the price is worse now. If I didn't buy it back than, I could have been disappointed." - am I using could have been correctly?

Answer (score 1):

No. *Could have been* refers to a possibility that existed in the past. "If I had not had my umbrella with me when it rained yesterday, I could have got very wet."

You are glad you *bought* the product before the sale. If you *had not bought* it then, you could be disappointed *now* because the price is (presumably) higher.